# Opening a window in my application to validate google credentials

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the following to validate google credentials to use the google drive API in my application...

```
//Setup and cache credientials
UserCredential credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
  scopes,
  "user",
  CancellationToken.None,
  new FileDataStore(m_CredentialFilePath, true)).Result;
```

This works great and does open a browser window for the user to login to their google account and validate access to my application.

Is it possible to somehow use a browser control in my application to show that login page and validate access?

Also, is it possible to somehow do this asynchronously or will I need to just create a new task thread to handle the request so not to tie up the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to open the auth window in a web browser control, this isn't currently supported by the client library.   There have been a number of issue requests for this and one pull request that I am aware of that would have added it

Add option to use Winforms embedded browser [#547](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/665)

Unfortunately the developers on the project decided not to merge that pull request.

As for your asynchronously idea, no idea but it might be fun to try.

**Side note:**

You might want to switch to .net 4.5 now 4.0 is no longer supported.

Comment: I have plans on switching to the latest version of VS but can't right now.  I just ended up putting the auth request in a task the way I always do.  I didn't realize at first that all it was doing is creating it's own task and returning it's own new task.  ;)  I was hoping more then anything that I could just get it to open in it's own window.  I personally use 4-6 monitors and when I went to go auth it popped up way on the other side of my monitor array...  Just by chance I noticed it, but a user using my app might not..  :/

Comment: The only thing I could think of to get where I want to go is set the default browser to IE (eww), open up a new IE window, set the position and size to my liking, then try to auth...  It will use the last open browser window.

Comment: I have been working with the Client library for years I have tried everything I can think of.  :)

Comment: no that is to crazy even for me :)  I ended up making my own library loosely based upon the official one where I could get the Auth URI myself.

Comment: With all your experience, have you ever gotten the CancellationToken to work when calling GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()?

Comment: Nope nor have I tried very hard, I am not all that helpful am I.